# MySQL or Hibernate caching issue receiving old data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, caching

I am facing one weird issue when I update the table and after a couple of seconds when I try to fetch that then I still receive the old data. When I again fetch with same query after couple of second then I receive refreshed data. Basically what I see is it takes some time to return the fresh data.

I have disabled all caching from hibernate also while fetching I am making session.clear() and marked query as uncachable.

I also look into mysql query log and I figured out that hibernate is querying to mysql, but I am receiving old data.

How can I make sure that at any given point of time I receive refreshed data only

Below is my hibernate config file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>  
    <property name="show_sql">true</property> 

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:4804/aluminidb?autoReconnect=true</property>  
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>  
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <!-- Example mapping file inclusion -->

    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property> 
    <mapping resource="com/alumini/spring/model/Alumini.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/alumini/spring/model/Question.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/alumini/spring/model/Events.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
```

Below is the code to fetch the object

```
@Override
public Alumini login(String email, String password) {
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.clear();
    Transaction t;
    try{
        t=session.beginTransaction(); 
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("chkLogIn");
        query.setParameter("email",email);
        query.setParameter("password",password);
        query.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH);
        query.setCacheable(false);
        List<Alumini> aluminiList=query.list();
        if(aluminiList!=null && aluminiList.size()>0){
            System.out.println(aluminiList.get(0).getLastUpdated());
            t.commit();
            return aluminiList.get(0);
        }else{
            t.rollback();
            return null;
        }
    }finally{
        session.close();
    }   
}
```

So I am clearing the session, also in my config I have set all cache disabled. still when I update the record and if with in couple of seconds if I fetch the record using above method then I receive old data for once. After that it gives me latest data.

Comment: Do you get old data when you query from outside your code using your db developer tool?

Comment: no I don't, get old data. I believe its some seconds lag in updating cache.

Comment: will you please share your hibernate config along with sessionfactory bean and transaction manager if any

Answer (score 0):

If some entities are loaded in the current Session and you run a [native query](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-dark-side-of-hibernate-auto-flush/), the Session might not flush automatically.

Hibernate Session offers [application-level repeatable reads](http://vladmihalcea.com/the-dark-side-of-hibernate-auto-flush/), so if other database transaction changes an entity, Hibernate will not refresh the current entity states.

Now, since you did not post the UPDATE part, it's hard to tell what you are doing there. The best way to address this issues is to simply log all JDBC statements as [explained in this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-log-jdbc-statements/). Then, you will know for sure whether the update was executed or not.

More, the way you do transaction and Session management is flawed as well. You don't even rollback in a `finally` block, and since you are using MySQL, this can lead to locks being held and causing deadlocks.

Just use a framework like Spring or Java EE to handle the Persistence Context and transaction management for you.

In your example:

```
Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
session.clear();
```

How can one tell whether this is a new `Session`, and calling `clear` would not make any sense, or it is the same `Session` you used for the update?

From this code, I would assume that this is the case:

```
if(aluminiList!=null && aluminiList.size()>0){
    System.out.println(aluminiList.get(0).getLastUpdated());
    t.commit();
    return aluminiList.get(0);
}else{
    t.rollback();
    return null;
}
```

But it points out that you might have skipped the [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html) and jumped to coding Hibernate.

1. The `aluminiList` can never be null. It can only be empty.
2. Logging via `System.out` is wrong. Use a Logging framework for that.
3. Why do you want to commit after the query was executed? Maybe the change was not flushed at all and the query did not trigger the flush because either you set the `FlushMode.MANUAL` or the query is a native SQL, not a JPQL. Check out [this article for more details about the difference](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-the-auto-flush-work-in-jpa-and-hibernate/).
4. You call `rollback` on else? What's the point? You don't trust the database that it issued the UPDATE properly and now you want to roll back that change. Or, you suspect that Hibernate did not flush, but then, why do you would you roll it back if the change didn't happen, right? But if it happened, then you should read-your-writes because that's how [ACID isolation levels work](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/).

All in all, there are many issues in the code that you posted. So, read the Hibernate User Guide and [these tutorials](https://vladmihalcea.com/tutorials/hibernate/), and you will fix all your issues. There's no other way.

Comment: I did clear the session before using. check my updated answer..am I missing anytihng?

Comment: No, problem is yet not solved.. After updating if with in some seconds I try to fetch the data then I am receiving the older data.Still facing the issue..

Comment: Your code has way too many issues that the fact that you get stale data is merely a hint that you need to dodo massive changes to it: proper logging, statement logging, proper Session/Tx management.